# How to stop HTTPS redirection for a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Currently, I have following redirection setup in htaccess to redirect www and non-www URL to HTTPS with www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I have now created a subdomain `dev.example.com`. But when I run it, site redirects to HTTPS with www. How can I stop it, and load dev without any redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another condition to the HTTPS rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```